# count the number of days, how many days remained active on an offer In Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to count the number of days, how many days remained active on an offer.

That is my Tbale:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(u_id, , offer, status,status_date) as
SELECT 1,  'Offer_1', 'Active', TO_DATE('2021/12/01 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Offer_1', 'Deactive', TO_DATE('2022/02/01 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Offer_1','Active', TO_DATE('2022/03/01 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Offer_1','Deactive' TO_DATE('2022/04/01 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Offer_2','Active', TO_DATE('2022/12/30 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual
```

That is my script:

```
select distinct u_id,offer_id,
trunc(nvl(case when status = 'Deactive' then status_date end),sysdate) - 
trunc(case when status = 'Active' then status_date end) date_diff 
from myTable
```

but it gives me wrong result.

expected output:

| u_id | offer | total_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | offer_1 | 93 |
| 1 | offer_2 | 31 |

Comment: There's no ordering field in your rows, there's no way you can identify, within the same offer, when that begun and ended in a deterministic and reliable way.

Comment: Unless you say there's an error in your data, `'2021/03/01 21:02:44'` should be `'2022/03/01 21:02:44'` and there's always alternation between active and non-active status within the same offer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provided 'Active' and 'Deactive' are always alternating, you can use `LEAD` to get the desctive date for each active date. At last aggregate and sum.

```
select
  u_id,
  offer,
  trunc(sum(cast(next_status_date as date) - cast(status_date as date))) as total_days
from
(
  select
    u_id, offer, status, status_date,
    coalesce
    (
      lead(status_date) over (partition by u_id, offer order by status_date),
      sysdate
    ) as next_status_date
  from mytable
)
where status = 'Active'
group by u_id, offer
order by u_id, offer;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/YDVTqEiR

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows :

```
select u_id, offer, sum(case when status = 'Active' then ceil(trunc(sysdate) - status_date) else ceil(status_date - trunc(sysdate))  end) as total_day
from myTable
group by u_id, offer
```

Result :

```
U_ID    OFFER   TOTAL_DAY
1       Offer_1  460
1       Offer_2  31
```

`ceil` used to round the specified number up (number of days in this case)

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SLAKSXXO)